# What happens at a ramp check when I forgot my license and medical?

Tags: easa-regulations

I wonder what happens if I would get ramp checked and don’t have my license and medical with me. Especially in EASA territory. Anyone ever had this case?

Comment: FAA answer, hence the comment.  You'll have problems.  Assuming it is clear that you were flying without those documents, you are in violation of regulations and could face a penalty.  It's ultimately up to the agent, but it is a violation.

Comment: Since EASA delegates the implementation of regulations to individual countries it's likely that this depends partly on which country you're in. Different countries may have different penalties. Do you have a specific country in mind, or is it a general question?

Comment: @Pondlife Germany and Switzerland. Just asking for a friend. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you get ramp checked in a country under EASA jurisdiction, they will follow the [EASA ramp check SAFA procedures](https://www.easa.europa.eu/domains/air-operations/ramp-inspection-programmes-safa-saca), which include 53 points of inspection, not all of which may be performed during a check. Licenses are part of the inspection. Medical certificates are not mentioned, but I assume they are as well. Discrepancies found can be minor, significant or major. As a former auditor myself, I am going to make an educated guess that not having your license in your possession is the same as not having a license at all and would be a major discrepancy, and might result in the inspector directing the facility not to allow you to depart in your aircraft until you go get your license. It is almost 100% certain that the discrepancy would also be reported to the FAA.

At what stage of the flight the ramp check is performed will also make a difference, of course. Getting ramp checked before you leave and not having your license may result in nothing more than a stern warning and being told to go get it. You will likely not get off as easily if you are ramp checked as you are arriving in your aircraft.

Solution: **Follow your checklist** and verify your documentation prior to even starting the engine.

Comment: "It is almost 100% certain that the discrepancy would also be reported to the FAA" Did you mean to EASA?

Comment: Would it help any if the pilot showed electronic copies on their phone/tablet?

Comment: No, I meant the FAA. And whether or not the ramp inspector will accept electronic reproductions of the documents is a crapshoot.

Comment: @JuanJimenez Isn't there any difference between flying internationally and domestically (in the country of issue of licenses and plane registration)?

Comment: @Afe That should be obvious from the fact that I pointed out my answer is for EASA countries. In the US you have to have your license with you or you risk a fine, and maybe even being arrested if the inspector reports it to the police.

Comment: @JuanJimenez, Jurisdiction matters… local police have no more authority to arrest you for flying without your pilot certificate than a FSDO inspector would have to pull you over for speeding in your car.

Comment: FAA Regulations 61.3(l) and 61.51(i)(1) state that a person must present his or her certificates, authorizations, identification, and other documents required under Part 61 for inspection upon a request by the administrator, NTSB, or any federal, state, or local law enforcement officer. This gives local LEO's the right to arrest you if you refuse to do so. States do not have to reciprocate arrest authority to the FAA for federal regulations to be enforced.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S. if you are ramp-checked *before* you operate an aircraft there would be no issue since FARs [61.3](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.3) and [61.23](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.23) do not require certificates unless you are serving as a crewmember or exercising pilot privileges (which you aren't unless you are operating an aircraft).

If you were operating an aircraft without the certificates (Pilot and/or Medical certificates) in your "possession," but you actually have the proper and current certificates, you're likely to get off with verbal counseling or a Warning Notice (my opinion). Don't know about EASA territory.